# Why can't European users access my site?

Tags: domain-name-system, connection

My site has been running just fine for the past couple of years, but all of a sudden, two days ago, European users have been experiencing serious connection problems to the site.  I really want to fix this for them, but what's the best way to figure out what the issue is?  I have absolutely no connection problems to the site on my end, nor do Asian or other American users it seems.  Using just-ping.com, some European servers come back with some packet losses.  I tried doing some traceroutes from European servers to my own, but they all seemed to work just fine.

I'd at least like to be able to tell users that if the problem does not lie with my server, then it at least lies somewhere out of my control.  I really want to figure out what the choke point is though.  Is there another way I might be able to find out why they can't seem to connect to the site?  Just looking for any other ideas from people that have had a similar experience.

Answer (score 1):

I would first make sure they they are resolving the IP correctly.  If that works, you will want a couple traceroutes from the clients (Or at least their public IPs).  You can then give that information to your ISP and they should be able to find out what is wrong.  It does sound like it is probably not your server.

Maybe [just-traceroute](http://just-traceroute.com/) will be able to show you where the packet loss is happening or places where there are big jumps in latency.

Comment: In this case, the *pathping* command would probably be more useful than just a trace

Answer (score 0):

Are they all coming from the same country? This is a long shot, but there are regional differences in Antivirus/Firewall software. Eg: Many UK banking users are given Trusteer Rapport with their banking software. Many Finnish users use F-Secure. Might also be related to browsers: Norwegians use Opera more than other countries, etc.

Comment: The OP seemed to assume that it was a network problem, not an application one.

Answer (score 0):

Use [traceroute.org](http://www.traceroute.org/) to perform traceroutes from various places all over the world You'll get a better idea of what is going on. Asking traceroutes from clients is hopeless: they won't understand or send you a screenshot (yes, I've seen that) or forget to include important information.

Per Kyle Brandt's suggestion, use the name or the IP address of your service, to see if it makes a difference.